# Use isinstance to test for Unicode string

Tags: python, unicode, typechecking

How can I do something like:

```
>>> s = u'hello'
>>> isinstance(s,str)
False
```

But I would like `isinstance` to return `True` for this Unicode encoded string. Is there a Unicode string object type?

Comment: `type(s)` would have told you the type easily... but why are you type-checking? Are you really looking only for `unicode` objects, or anything with a string-like interface?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Test for `str`:

```
isinstance(unicode_or_bytestring, str)
```

or, if you must handle bytestrings, test for `bytes` separately:

```
isinstance(unicode_or_bytestring, bytes)
```

The two types are deliberately not exchangible; use explicit encoding (for `str` -> `bytes`) and decoding (`bytes` -> `str`) to convert between the types.

In *Python 2*, where the modern Python 3 `str` type is called `unicode` and `str` is the precursor of the Python 3 `bytes` type, you could use [`basestring`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#basestring) to test for **both**:

```
isinstance(unicode_or_bytestring, basestring)
```

`basestring` is only available in Python 2, and is the abstract base type of both [`str`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str) and [`unicode`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#unicode).

If you wanted to test for *just* `unicode`, then do so explicitly:

```
isinstance(unicode_tring, unicode)
```

Comment: @Anthony: indeed, `unicode` is specific to Python 2. In Python 3, use `str`.

Comment: so if i check for `basestring` in python 2.7 or python 3, I will get the same result?

Comment: @Gulzar: from my answer: *basestring is only available in Python 2*. So no.

Comment: Ok, how would you go about writing this as python 2 and 3 compatible?

Comment: @Gulzar: depends on the context. If you want to allow for *text*, then perhaps use a name error guard: `try: strtype = basestring`, `except NameError: strtype = str`, then use `isinstance(..., strtype)`.

Answer (score 10):

> Is there a Unicode string object type?

Yes, it is called [`unicode`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#unicode):

```
>>> s = u'hello'
>>> isinstance(s, unicode)
True
>>>
```

Note that in Python 3.x, this type was removed because [all strings are now Unicode](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit).

Answer (score 8):

> Is there a Unicode string object type?

Yes this works:

```
>>> s = u'hello'
>>> isinstance(s, unicode)
True
>>>
```

This is however only useful if you know that it is unicode.
Another solution is to use the [`six`](https://pythonhosted.org/six/) package, which saves you from python2.x and python3.x conversions and catches `unicode` and `str`

```
>>> unicode_s = u'hello'
>>> s = 'hello'
>>> isinstance(unicode_s, str)
False
>>> isinstance(unicode_s, unicode)
True
>>> isinstance(s, str)
True
>>> isinstance(unicode_s, str)
False
>>> isinstance(s, six.string_types)
True
>>> isinstance(unicode_s, six.string_types)
True
```

Comment: exactly what i was looking for. If you wanna make the code compatible for python2 and 3.